# Web push notification not coming on firefox when browser is closed

Tags: firefox, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I implemented web push notifications for chrome and firefox using service worker. Ideally users should be getting notification even if the browser is closed. It is happening correctly for chrome. But not working for firefox. In firefox, I am getting notifications when site is active, not when it is closed. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Web push notification not coming on firefox when browser is closed

That is the expected behavior. Currently (August 2017) Firefox needs to be open in order to receive push notifications. However it should work even if your website is closed: you only need to keep the browser open (e.g. push notifications should work if you are surfing other websites).

Comment: On Android Chrome, when the browser is closed it still displays the notification why it that?

Comment: @knight most apps run in the background, even if you close it. You would have to force stop the app and then you shouldn't get any notifications until you open it again.